What is the minimum size for a vineyard to be obligated against Kilayim
According to Halacha, a vineyard is prohibited from being mixed with different fruits or seeds, also known as Kilayim. My question is what is the minimum size/shiur for a vineyard to exist by halachic standards and for this prohibition to apply?

A single vine already prohibits from planting seeds around it, see the language of the mishna in Kilayim 3:7

We find that [the gourd] is treated more stringently than a vine,
since for a single vine he must give six handbreadths for it to be
worked, but for a single gourd a bet rova.

The Rambam confirms one can only plant six tefachim away from a single vine (MT Kilayim 7:1)

From a single vine, he should move six handbreadths away and sow.


But for a vineyard (5 vines) the buffer area is bigger

This is correct but, if I may, not relevant to the question, which was focused on the minimum-sized vineyard
